# Canvas2D: Multiple readback operations using getImageData are faster with the willReadFrequently attribute set to true

Tags: performance, here-api, heremaps

I'm troubleshooting performance because of users complaining of low FPS & I seem to be getting this warning and any attempts to trace it leads me to HERE's **built-in functions**.

I think I understand what it means, and perhaps it's not the root of the problem, but it's my only lead.
Other than that the project is applying everything from HERE's 'Best Practices' doc.

Also, any tips that can help improve performance are **GREATLY** appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: First, it is needed to ask you for clarification:

- Since when they noticed the drop in performance?<br \>
- What version of the API are they using?  
- Tested API features + reproducible code is missing

Comment: First, it is needed to ask you for clarification:

- **Since when they noticed the drop in performance?**
- **What version of the API are they using?**  
- **Tested API features + reproducible code is missing**

Answer (score 0):

This message "Canvas2D: Multiple readback operations using getImageData are faster with the willReadFrequently attribute set to true" is not any more appeared in console log.

Users complaining of low FPS because perhaps they utilize the devices with weak graphic card. Try please to utilize P2D engine or HARP engine instead of WEBGL.

HARP https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/style-editor/change-harp-style-at-load :

```
/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

// Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
// In your own code, replace variable window.apikey with your own apikey

var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: window.apikey
});

// Step 2: specify engine type. In this example, we use HARP rendering engine, which is capable
// of rendering vector data using the style configuration exported from the HERE Style Editor.
// HARP engine is not the default engine, and it's not included in the mapsjs-core.js module.
// To use this engine, you need to include mapsjs-harp.js file to your HTML page
var engineType = H.Map.EngineType['HARP'];

// Step 3: create the style object from the style configuration
// exported from the HERE Style Editor. The argument is a style path
var style = new H.map.render.harp.Style('https://heremaps.github.io/maps-api-for-javascript-examples/change-harp-style-at-load/data/night.json');

// Step 4: create a layer with the style object:
var vectorLayer = platform.getOMVService().createLayer(style, { engineType });

// Step 5: initialize a map
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  vectorLayer, {
  engineType,
  center: {lat: 52.51477270923461, lng: 13.39846691425174},
  zoom: 13,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});
// add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

//Step 6: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
```

P2D (Raster Tile API v3):
https://demo.support.here.com/examples/v3.1/simple_raster_v3_map

```
/*
author Alexander Sadovoy
(C) HERE 2022-2023
*/
// check if the site was loaded via secure connection
var secure = (location.protocol === 'https:') ? true : false;

// Create a platform object to communicate with the HERE REST APIs
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    apikey: api_key_rts,
    useHTTPS: secure
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers({
    engineType: H.Map.EngineType['P2D']
});

//Base raster
const rasterTileService = platform.getRasterTileService({
    format: 'jpeg',//or png, png8
    queryParams: {
        lang: 'en',
        ppi: getPpi(),
        style: 'explore.day',
        features: 'pois:all,environmental_zones:all,congestion_zones:all,vehicle_restrictions:active_and_inactive'
    },
});
const rasterTileProvider = new H.service.rasterTile.Provider(rasterTileService, {
    engineType: H.Map.EngineType.P2D,
    tileSize: 512
});
const rasterTileLayer = new H.map.layer.TileLayer(rasterTileProvider);
//rasterTileLayer.addEventListener("update", e => {console.log("update e:", e);});

//Base raster
const rasterNightTileService = platform.getRasterTileService({
    format: 'jpeg',//or png, png8
    queryParams: {
        lang: 'en',
        ppi: getPpi(),
        style: 'explore.night',
        features: 'pois:all,environmental_zones:all,congestion_zones:all,vehicle_restrictions:active_and_inactive'
    },
});
const rasterNightTileProvider = new H.service.rasterTile.Provider(rasterNightTileService, {
    engineType: H.Map.EngineType.P2D,
    tileSize: 512
});
const rasterNightTileLayer = new H.map.layer.TileLayer(rasterNightTileProvider);


//Satellite
const satellTileService = platform.getRasterTileService({
    format: 'jpeg',
    queryParams: {
        lang: 'en',
        ppi: getPpi(),
        style: 'explore.satellite.day',
        features: 'pois:all,environmental_zones:all,congestion_zones:all,vehicle_restrictions:active_and_inactive'
    },
});
const satellTileProvider = new H.service.rasterTile.Provider(satellTileService, {
    engineType: H.Map.EngineType.P2D,
    tileSize: 512
});
const satellTileLayer = new H.map.layer.TileLayer(satellTileProvider);

var geocoder = platform.getSearchService();

// Instantiate a map in the 'map' div, set the base map to normal
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
    rasterTileLayer, {
        engineType: H.Map.EngineType.P2D,
        center: center,
        zoom: zoom,
        pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});


// Enable the map event system
var mapevents = new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map);

// Enable map interaction (pan, zoom, pinch-to-zoom)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(mapevents);
behavior.disable(H.mapevents.Behavior.Feature.FRACTIONAL_ZOOM);

// Enable the default UI
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);


ui.removeControl("mapsettings");
// create custom one
var ms = new H.ui.MapSettingsControl( {
    baseLayers : [ { 
            label:"Map view", layer: rasterTileLayer
        },{
            label:"Map view night", layer: rasterNightTileLayer
        },{
            label:"layers.satellite", layer: satellTileLayer
        }
    ],
    alignment: H.ui.LayoutAlignment.RIGHT_BOTTOM
});
ui.addControl("customized", ms);

//remove zoom buttons and add again with 'fractionalZoom: false'
ui.removeControl('zoom');
ui.addControl('zoom', new H.ui.ZoomControl({
    fractionalZoom: false,
    alignment: H.ui.LayoutAlignment.RIGHT_BOTTOM
})); 



window.addEventListener('resize', function() { map.getViewPort().resize(); });


function getPpi(){
    return (window.devicePixelRatio >= 1.7 ? 400 : 100);
}
let txtForGeoSearchEl = document.getElementById("txtForGeoSearch");
let onPressButton = e => {
    //console.log("e: tap", e);
    if(e.type == "keypress" && e.key !== "Enter" ){
        return;
    }
    let txtForGeoSearch = txtForGeoSearchEl.value;
    geocoder.geocode(
        {
            q: txtForGeoSearch
        },
        r => {
            if(!r.items[0]){
                alert(`Address '${txtForGeoSearch}' was not found`);
                return;
            }
            let loc = r.items[0];
            //console.log("loc:", loc);
            map.setCenter(loc.position);
            let zLevel = 10;
            if(loc.resultType){
                zLevel = 12;
                if(loc.resultType == "houseNumber"){
                    zLevel = 18;
                }else if(loc.resultType == "street"){
                    zLevel = 16;
                }else if(loc.resultType == "locality" && loc.localityType && loc.localityType == "postalCode"){
                    zLevel = 15
                }
            }
            map.setZoom(zLevel);
        },
        e => {
            console.log("error:", e);
        }
    );
};

document.getElementById("runGeo").addEventListener("click", onPressButton);
txtForGeoSearchEl.addEventListener("keypress", onPressButton);
```